# Is it possible to make desktop visible behind drawn object using SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2, c

I would like to draw an avatar over the desktop, something similar to those word 97 assistants, my idea so far is to make only the background transparent but I haven't had any luck, any suggestion? is it possible to make with SDL2?

Answer (score 1):

- You could try `SDL_SetWindowShape` which [is implemented](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/d2fcd08e539f879ba1cfe864a5fd310cf8deb72b/src/video/SDL_shape.c#L259) but is [not officially documented](https://wiki.libsdl.org/ToDo), probably because it does not work well on all supported platforms. It may work for major platforms though (Windows, macOS, X11/Mir/DirectFB)
- Try this Windows-only approach: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4052940/2038264 The caveat is that graphics performance will be very slow since it involves coping GPU data to RAM every frame

Answer (score 0):

Not with SDL directly. These sorts of things are generally accomplished by [getting the DC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdc) of the [desktop window](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdesktopwindow) and drawing to it using GDI. I'm not sure how well that technique works with the window composition manager of modern Windows.

You could also look at using [`SetWindowRgn`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn) to define a non-rectangular window. This imposes some pretty strict limits on the overall outline of your little avatar though.